# Treat content of a column as numbers, not a boxes

Tags: tables, calculations

I'm making documentation for data communication protocol and trying to make a table column which shows an offset of the message fields, calculated for each field (table row) and takes field width instead. For offset calculation I made a counter, which keeps current offset, and define new command:

```
\newcounter{bytepos}
\newcommand{\fieldwidth}[1]{%
\ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{1}%
{\thebytepos\stepcounter{bytepos}}
{\thebytepos--\the\numexpr\value{bytepos} + #1 - 1\relax\addtocounter{bytepos}{#1}}%
}
```

I also define new column type, which should call my command for every item in the column:

```
\newsavebox{\byteposbox}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\begin{lrbox}{\byteposbox}}%
l%
<{\end{lrbox}%
\fieldwidth{\usebox{\byteposbox}}%
}}
```

For populating table I use next sample code:

```
\begin{tabular}{Bl}
  2 & Start mark   \\
  8 & Message data \\
  4 & Service info \\
  1 & Checksum     \\
  1 & End mark
 \end{tabular}
```

It should be compiled as like as

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
   0-- 1 & Start mark   \\
   2-- 9 & Message data \\
  10--13 & Service info \\
  14     & Checksum     \\
  15     & End mark
\end{tabular}
```

But I gave “missing number, treated as zero” instead. After searching in network I found that numbers in LaTeX is something special, and it's looks like \usebox returns complete and glued box, not a text, which cannot be converted back to raw text.

How can I get raw text from every row? Or maybe my understanding is wrong and I missing something simple and important?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to manipulate count registers than boxes

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcount\zzthis
\newcount\zztotal
\newcommand\zzrange{%
\the\zztotal
\global\zztotal=\numexpr\zztotal+\zzthis-1\relax
\ifnum\zzthis>1--\the\zztotal\fi
\global\advance\zztotal1
}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\let\ignorespaces\empty\afterassignment\zzrange\zzthis=}l}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{Bl}
  2 & Start mark   \\
  8 & Message data \\
  4 & Service info \\
  1 & Checksum     \\
  1 & End mark
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```